# Using PHP to Run Query on SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an internal tool for my team to retrieve data on products based on manufacturer SKU numbers. I tested an idea on my website where you upload a CSV file with a list of SKUs into the MYSQL database using LOAD DATA INFILE through PHP, then output the results into a table using SELECT/JOIN.

The issue with this would be if multiple users upload the CSV at the same time, their results would be combined.

Is there a way to query between a database and CSV file without uploading to the database or a possible way to differentiate each user so their results aren't combined?

Basic elements for the tables would include

CSV File (Currently being imported into a MYSQL table)

| Manufacturer | SKU |
| --- | --- |
| MFG_A | 123 |
| MFG_A | 456 |
| MFG_A | 789 |

Database File

| Manufacturer | SKU | Description | AVG_Price | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MFG_A | 123 | T-Shirt | 1.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 456 | Sweater | 5.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 789 | Pants | 3.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 999 | Shorts | 2.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 888 | Shoes | 8.00 | PR |

RESULTS

```
SELECT a.*, b.Description, b.AVG_Price, b.UOM
FROM CSV_Table a
LEFT JOIN Database_Table b
on a.Manufacturer = b.Manufacturer
and a.SKU = b.SKU;
```

| Manufacturer | SKU | Description | AVG_Price | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MFG_A | 123 | T-Shirt | 1.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 456 | Sweater | 5.00 | EA |
| MFG_A | 789 | Pants | 3.00 | EA |

Comment: You can use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` for a table for the current connection. It won't interfere with tables created by other users.

Comment: Exactly what I was look for! Never heard of that before! Thanks!